# Why and how JSON Parse of an exponential value gives a number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a decimal precision function which takes in an object and a precision number as arguments and it returns me a number which is parsed using `JSON.parse(number)` as output. 
I have observed that the `toPrecision()` function returns a value in exponential notation when the value passed is an integer with no decimal places and the precision value is between 1 and 100. When I pass in the exponential notation to the `JSON.parse()`, it gives me a number. I am not understanding how this is working internally. Could anyone explain me what exactly is happening here. The following is the function which I have devised:

```
function precise(object, precision){
   let st = JSON.stringify(object);
   st = st.replace(/[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+/g, s => parseFloat(s).toPrecision(precision));
   return JSON.parse(st);
}
```

For instance, if I call precise(100, 2), st will have the value 1.0e+2 and the return value will be 100. How does this conversion taking place?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you not know you can do this in js: `var n = 1.0e+10;`?

Comment: If `st` ends up being `'1.0e+2'` after the replace operation, you can reduce your example to simply `JSON.parse('1.0e+2')`. You'll notice if you type `1.0e+2` into a JS console that the result will be `100`.

Comment: What is the point of all that code? What is it you're trying to achieve? Really, JavaScript only has one kind of number, and there's not much you can do to change that.

Comment: Here, the function can take in any object like JSON and the regex will find the numbers and reduce them down to whatever precision value has been passed into the function. That was my plan, to achieve the decimal precise values if they are present in any object or a floating point number which is passed to the given function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly it is essentially...

"Why does `console.log((100).toPrecision(2));` result in `1.0e+2`?"

The argument that is given to `toPrecision` defines the desired number of precision (aka "scientific precision" or number of digits (not decimal places)).

In other words... there are more than two digits in `100` so the result has to be defined using scientific notation.